# How to find multiple minimum values from a list of sublists?

Tags: python-3.x

I have GPS coordinates for RRH and BBU:

```
RRH: [[41.38988253, 2.129556023, '1'], [41.38745915, 2.126436603, '2'], [41.3929439, 2.143336753, '3'], [41.39109767, 2.135616075, '4'], [41.39496903, 2.138040811, '5'], [41.39414659, 2.137729336, '6'], [41.38440257, 2.119681252, '7'], [41.3535301, 2.144453223, '8'], [41.35552416, 2.137000697, '9'], [41.35258318, 2.148086036, '10'], [41.35130853, 2.140463315, '11'], [41.38765528, 2.121350735, '12'], [41.36445154, 2.132837518, '13'], [41.36144746, 2.130147294, '14'], [41.34995663, 2.144620381, '15'], [41.38124426, 2.118779226, '16'], [41.36352164, 2.134464983, '17'], [41.3904652, 2.13343991, '18'], [41.39335171, 2.135858918, '19'], [41.38860314, 2.135873516, '20'], [41.39195119, 2.139388009, '21'], [41.40584116, 2.215194359, '22'], [41.41060962, 2.22285246, '23'], [41.40801101, 2.211823094, '24'], [41.40174968, 2.213648607, '25'], [41.40881323, 2.215466548, '26'], [41.40876677, 2.217668089, '27'], [41.40393753, 2.190354235, '28'], [41.40309294, 2.191549143, '29'], [41.40421413, 2.193764487, '30'], [41.40198954, 2.188620978, '31'], [41.40540358, 2.187300951, '32'], [41.3988891, 2.190027392, '33'], [41.40488006, 2.184768114, '34'], [41.40656225, 2.186155734, '35'], [41.4032534, 2.183736817, '36'], [41.40742083, 2.191097044, '37'], [41.39982978, 2.194269803, '38'], [41.38723668, 2.129851845, '39'], [41.39034394, 2.124049766, '40'], [41.38648798, 2.122911378, '41'], [41.40668683, 2.193266381, '42'], [41.41341636, 2.218966707, '43'], [41.41339722, 2.222205598, '44'], [41.39375604, 2.140802106, '45'], [41.38818833, 2.128579772, '46'], [41.38589634, 2.115121354, '47'], [41.39037831, 2.137155264, '48'], [41.40888641, 2.218998806, '49'], [41.41149706, 2.227529451, '50'], [41.407576, 2.217833448, '51'], [41.40577599, 2.190513005, '52'], [41.40461468, 2.190262216, '53'], [41.36564597, 2.131829909, '54'], [41.36489012, 2.131611604, '55'], [41.3655079, 2.13350979, '56'], [41.3545356, 2.138947744, '57'], [41.35294958, 2.138810688, '58'], [41.35525513, 2.142080929, '59'], [41.38541285, 2.117792843, '60'], [41.40350203, 2.16165616, '61'], [41.39407746, 2.163295498, '62'], [41.40256563, 2.159653646, '63'], [41.40345137, 2.158732677, '64'], [41.40573486, 2.160594926, '65'], [41.40544246, 2.158677166, '66'], [41.4042025, 2.156580309, '67'], [41.40639032, 2.156391287, '68'], [41.40497179, 2.154232881, '69'], [41.40737523, 2.158183354, '70'], [41.40208867, 2.154838201, '71'], [41.40271803, 2.152349074, '72'], [41.40072331, 2.157982016, '73'], [41.40094072, 2.152824619, '74'], [41.40515581, 2.151148606, '75'], [41.39161495, 2.154777093, '76'], [41.39164912, 2.1502518, '77'], [41.3933277, 2.153140256, '78'], [41.38964343, 2.155062515, '79'], [41.39104607, 2.158508685, '80'], [41.38904977, 2.15814747, '81'], [41.38731735, 2.155917023, '82'], [41.38731395, 2.151280403, '83'], [41.38455081, 2.148338702, '84'], [41.38051089, 2.1491282, '85'], [41.38050935, 2.154302387, '86'], [41.3830847, 2.153219841, '87'], [41.37746396, 2.152994102, '88'], [41.37864266, 2.158372984, '89'], [41.38162664, 2.160132284, '90'], [41.38477989, 2.157736848, '91'], [41.39646026, 2.166359429, '92'], [41.39531549, 2.161977489, '93'], [41.39386582, 2.165235745, '94'], [41.39303263, 2.168665537, '95'], [41.39052591, 2.16766681, '96'], [41.39528298, 2.170973353, '97'], [41.39307377, 2.173802557, '98'], [41.39026389, 2.172233558, '99'], [41.39198357, 2.176844408, '100'], [41.38705505, 2.168349986, '101'], [41.38580475, 2.169337344, '102'], [41.38489202, 2.170894091, '103'], [41.38374847, 2.170944317, '104'], [41.38320131, 2.171871154, '105'], [41.38229848, 2.171974446, '106'], [41.38164839, 2.172520899, '107'], [41.38141647, 2.173589097, '108'], [41.38060403, 2.173336928, '109'], [41.37981981, 2.174131261, '110'], [41.37907178, 2.175426808, '111'], [41.37856088, 2.176158937, '112'], [41.37770398, 2.175726781, '113'], [41.37723853, 2.176857279, '114'], [41.37667486, 2.177878565, '115'], [41.38657664, 2.171501454, '116'], [41.38796178, 2.17078609, '117'], [41.38852804, 2.172406557, '118'], [41.38889536, 2.168287986, '119'], [41.39089217, 2.165811636, '120'], [41.39265104, 2.163642299, '121'], [41.39437496, 2.161499581, '122'], [41.39594399, 2.159692488, '123'], [41.38726061, 2.17415253, '124'], [41.3867827, 2.17525906, '125'], [41.38613137, 2.175649167, '126'], [41.3854995, 2.176295834, '127'], [41.3851489, 2.176954444, '128'], [41.38455147, 2.175213232, '129'], [41.38377194, 2.174609471, '130'], [41.38284373, 2.176761578, '131'], [41.38426326, 2.178683726, '132'], [41.38321941, 2.179508837, '133'], [41.38554138, 2.173372772, '134'], [41.38070946, 2.17799329, '135'], [41.37906733, 2.1798861, '136'], [41.38106167, 2.181434062, '137'], [41.38414004, 2.18409775, '138'], [41.38487256, 2.185618739, '139'], [41.3829069, 2.186158478, '140'], [41.39647318, 2.158142169, '141'], [41.39541995, 2.156254351, '142'], [41.39543435, 2.153929413, '143'], [41.39442252, 2.152344159, '144'], [41.39458675, 2.150402206, '145'], [41.39349639, 2.148882225, '146'], [41.39309984, 2.146997441, '147'], [41.39269047, 2.145737024, '148'], [41.39216, 2.144617541, '149'], [41.39212191, 2.143791101, '150'], [41.39151727, 2.141423138, '151'], [41.39087681, 2.138892682, '152'], [41.37951535, 2.123255434, '153'], [41.38234159, 2.122750756, '154'], [41.38076059, 2.121654553, '155'], [41.38158784, 2.12511256, '156'], [41.37973609, 2.142609535, '157'], [41.38070643, 2.140787318, '158'], [41.37912693, 2.140125029, '159'], [41.38558235, 2.196101422, '160'], [41.38373742, 2.194310782, '161'], [41.38872536, 2.191850873, '162'], [41.39104446, 2.189013813, '163'], [41.38964624, 2.183705985, '164'], [41.3756532, 2.176672921, '165'], [41.37445512, 2.174137286, '166'], [41.37511963, 2.172150053, '167'], [41.37469855, 2.170009728, '168'], [41.37522149, 2.167265619, '169'], [41.37477745, 2.164891338, '170'], [41.37525678, 2.163534026, '171'], [41.37469573, 2.1615999, '172'], [41.37530681, 2.159561563, '173'], [41.37476511, 2.157728066, '174'], [41.37530116, 2.155975208, '175'], [41.3752681, 2.152972091, '176'], [41.37559207, 2.15040038, '177'], [41.38912147, 2.200525494, '178'], [41.37606258, 2.149193449, '179'], [41.37382267, 2.148593761, '180'], [41.37365726, 2.150790153, '181'], [41.3722869, 2.148909567, '182'], [41.37338846, 2.154652807, '183'], [41.3763164, 2.189202428, '184'], [41.37797628, 2.188494739, '185'], [41.37944773, 2.187923778, '186'], [41.37859323, 2.191248351, '187'], [41.38123405, 2.187259818, '188'], [41.37918489, 2.155172675, '189'], [41.38143976, 2.156791124, '190'], [41.38303894, 2.160313106, '191'], [41.38562105, 2.162507838, '192'], [41.38627958, 2.164671358, '193'], [41.38811461, 2.164473477, '194'], [41.38904783, 2.162547839, '195'], [41.38867274, 2.159556719, '196'], [41.37814521, 2.170763199, '197'], [41.39856273, 2.181141831, '198'], [41.39706339, 2.177725078, '199'], [41.39543338, 2.174173142, '200'], [41.40595965, 2.196085956, '201'], [41.40590057, 2.198644551, '202'], [41.40822011, 2.201575706, '203'], [41.40690119, 2.202357761, '204'], [41.408396, 2.204834417, '205'], [41.40866122, 2.207238278, '206'], [41.40847209, 2.206574199, '207'], [41.40842553, 2.20897442, '208'], [41.40989058, 2.211958916, '209'], [41.4078404, 2.199451041, '210'], [41.42994945, 2.199672708, '211'], [41.42871317, 2.197970163, '212'], [41.42886609, 2.204068146, '213'], [41.42635501, 2.200254099, '214'], [41.42572176, 2.208256698, '215'], [41.42727818, 2.204374155, '216'], [41.42332817, 2.196548327, '217'], [41.4250889, 2.197223711, '218'], [41.42694172, 2.195373298, '219'], [41.43267828, 2.197860268, '220'], [41.40703161, 2.153612625, '221'], [41.40816405, 2.155696109, '222'], [41.40867073, 2.152077178, '223'], [41.41021455, 2.149881192, '224'], [41.40856448, 2.147062842, '225'], [41.41058356, 2.147931309, '226'], [41.40941309, 2.145606571, '227'], [41.4070378, 2.146164866, '228'], [41.41057942, 2.158529623, '229'], [41.40915937, 2.159776124, '230'], [41.39910639, 2.157642354, '231'], [41.39946885, 2.1601829, '232'], [41.39742936, 2.16204943, '233'], [41.39786889, 2.165887234, '234'], [41.39909312, 2.168827544, '235'], [41.39967085, 2.173128868, '236'], [41.40094963, 2.176077127, '237'], [41.40239839, 2.174188933, '238'], [41.40303716, 2.178815456, '239'], [41.40105048, 2.180930452, '240'], [41.40180775, 2.16680983, '241'], [41.40074303, 2.165274684, '242'], [41.40160211, 2.170797932, '243'], [41.40527925, 2.175215203, '244'], [41.40578643, 2.181131991, '245'], [41.4057811, 2.165305951, '246'], [41.40632458, 2.169821608, '247'], [41.40947235, 2.165138472, '248'], [41.40615597, 2.16290471, '249'], [41.40899559, 2.163609208, '250'], [41.41162898, 2.164328687, '251'], [41.40415872, 2.167584134, '252'], [41.40934147, 2.172128646, '253'], [41.41095553, 2.170031558, '254'], [41.40775853, 2.166686358, '255'], [41.40785995, 2.174679854, '256'], [41.41081219, 2.174542492, '257'], [41.40721475, 2.177817663, '258'], [41.40971316, 2.1789005, '259'], [41.41183357, 2.177744727, '260'], [41.38720667, 2.197712891, '261'], [41.38797421, 2.19511995, '262'], [41.38954698, 2.197268152, '263'], [41.39170675, 2.199937827, '264'], [41.39335424, 2.202052066, '265'], [41.38124352, 2.192809131, '266'], [41.37075116, 2.156721231, '267'], [41.37003354, 2.150872323, '268'], [41.36598669, 2.137806, '269'], [41.3671078, 2.14043114, '270'], [41.36629935, 2.136886419, '271'], [41.40244212, 2.193566064, '272'], [41.40338457, 2.197149137, '273'], [41.40147665, 2.197388361, '274'], [41.40429076, 2.199376949, '275'], [41.39955167, 2.195996457, '276'], [41.40156317, 2.199910671, '277'], [41.39941119, 2.198182841, '278'], [41.39747841, 2.197920138, '279'], [41.39916766, 2.200553512, '280'], [41.39742986, 2.200637056, '281'], [41.39771604, 2.202732102, '282'], [41.39760922, 2.204672685, '283'], [41.39649475, 2.203286769, '284'], [41.39715776, 2.205623271, '285'], [41.42645327, 2.202375412, '286'], [41.42849034, 2.20477867, '287'], [41.42781111, 2.20620115, '288'], [41.42467475, 2.203392208, '289'], [41.42710869, 2.207678204, '290'], [41.42416437, 2.205934769, '291'], [41.42370113, 2.210090139, '292'], [41.40610086, 2.149617997, '293'], [41.40662625, 2.148883385, '294'], [41.4077921, 2.150012055, '295'], [41.40693465, 2.15091706, '296'], [41.40565244, 2.150263277, '297'], [41.4045975, 2.150030929, '298'], [41.4038193, 2.150290792, '299'], [41.40210728, 2.150488432, '300']]

BBU: [[41.38227061, 2.128611835, '1'], [41.39517376, 2.147391488, '2'], [41.40538329, 2.156731836, '3'], [41.40832257, 2.168647219, '4'], [41.40323209, 2.206633545, '5'], [41.39397106, 2.193518883, '6'], [41.38212698, 2.189586642, '7'], [41.41882802, 2.199257871, '8'], [41.35910284, 2.136974551, '9'], [41.38131931, 2.176102407, '10'], [41.38918794, 2.177094309, '11'], [41.39325006, 2.156269437, '12'], [41.38385621, 2.161888675, '13'], [41.37208181, 2.162537181, '14'], [41.376809, 2.144989163, '15'], [41.40015888, 2.178641263, '16'], [41.42046079, 2.182838054, '17'], [41.40103642, 2.161985998, '18']]
```

The code I've written, calculates all possible distances between RRHs and BBUs and stores it in a multidimension lists with the following structure:

```
# Structure variables "distances"
distances = [[calculated_distance, BBU_id, RRH_id]]
Example: [[115.6, 3, 68]]
```

To sum up, I have a list of sublists, of 5400 entries.

What I'd like now is to store, out of the distances varibles, in another list, let's calle it "connected_sites", the minimum distance of each RRH to a BBU. So it will end up with a list of 300 sublists.

I don't know how to pick from all the distances the minimums ones for every RRH.

This is the  code:

```
# Libraries
import math
import csv
import operator
# -------------------------------- FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------
# Calculates the distance between two GPS coordinates
def haversine(coord1, coord2):
    R = 6372800  # Earth radius in meters
    lat1, lon1 = coord1
    lat2, lon2 = coord2

    phi1, phi2 = math.radians(lat1), math.radians(lat2) 
    dphi       = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlambda    = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)

    a = math.sin(dphi/2)**2 + \
        math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2)*math.sin(dlambda/2)**2

    return 2*R*math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))

# Convert GPS coordinates from str to float
def coord2float(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i][0]=float(l[i][0])
        l[i][1]=float(l[i][1])    
    return l


# MAIN

# Importing GPS coordinates    
RRH = []
BBU = []
i = 0
with open('sites.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    sites = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in sites:
        if i < 300:
            RRH.append(row)
            i+=1
        else:
            BBU.append(row)
# # Converting file coordinates into floats
RRH = coord2float(RRH)
BBU = coord2float(BBU)

# Calculating the distances between BBU and RRH
distances = []
for i in range(len(BBU)):
    for j in range(len(RRH)):
        coord1 = (BBU[i][0],BBU[i][1])
        coord2 = (RRH[j][0],RRH[j][1])     
        dist = haversine(coord1, coord2)
        distances.append([float("%.1f" % dist), 
                          int(BBU[i][2]),
                          int(RRH[j][2])])# Convert distance to float

distances = sorted(distances, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my mind `itertools.groupby` will solve this problem.  I made a copy of the data you provided, put it into the `sites.csv` and made a few tweaks to the code and added the lines needed to create `connected_sites`:

```
# Libraries
import csv
from itertools import groupby


def haversine(coord1, coord2):
    """Calculates the distance between two GPS coordinates"""
    from math import sin, cos, atan2, sqrt, radians
    R = 6372800  # Earth radius in meters
    lat1, lon1 = coord1
    lat2, lon2 = coord2
    phi1, phi2 = radians(lat1), radians(lat2)
    dphi = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlambda = radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = sin(dphi / 2)**2 + cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) * sin(dlambda / 2)**2
    return 2 * R * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))


def coord2float(lst):
    """Convert GPS coordinates from str to float"""
    for ll in lst:
        ll[0] = float(ll[0])
        ll[1] = float(ll[1])
    return lst

# MAIN

# Importing GPS coordinates
RRH = []
BBU = []
i = 0
with open('sites.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    sites = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in sites:
        if not row:
            continue
        if i < 300:
            RRH.append(row)
            i += 1
        else:
            BBU.append(row)
# # Converting file coordinates into floats
RRH = coord2float(RRH)
BBU = coord2float(BBU)

# Calculating the distances between BBU and RRH
distances = []
for i in range(len(BBU)):
    for j in range(len(RRH)):
        coord1 = (BBU[i][0], BBU[i][1])
        coord2 = (RRH[j][0], RRH[j][1])
        dist = haversine(coord1, coord2)
        distances.append([float("%.1f" % dist),
                          int(BBU[i][2]),
                          int(RRH[j][2])])  # Convert distance to float
```

Adding code to first sort the distances calculated with respect to the RRH id.  Then use `groupby` to iterate over each RRH id to calculate the minimum distance using `min` on the distances calculated for each RRH id:

```
distances.sort(key=lambda dd: dd[2])

connected_sites = []
for rrh_id, grouped_bbu in groupby(distances, key=lambda dd: dd[2]):
    dist4k = list(grouped_bbu)
    min_dist = min(dist4k, key=lambda dd: dd[0])
    connected_sites.append([min_dist, rrh_id])


print(f'Number connected sites: {len(connected_sites)}')
print(f'First two minimum distances: {connected_sites[:2]}')
print(f'Distances for first two sites: {distances[:36]}')
```

Running this code on the input data gives the output below. On insecption it is clear that the calculated minimum distance is correct.

```
Number connected sites: 300
First two minimum distances: [[[850.3, 1, 1], 1], [[605.0, 1, 2], 2]]
Distances for first two sites: [[850.3, 1, 1], [1600.4, 2, 1], 
[2848.5, 3, 1], [3852.8, 4, 1], [6600.3, 5, 1], [5356.6, 6, 1],
[5083.3, 7, 1], [6646.7, 8, 1], [3479.1, 9, 1], [3999.4, 10, 1], 
[3967.6, 11, 1], [2260.3, 12, 1], [2780.1, 13, 1], [3390.6, 14, 1], [1942.5, 15, 1], [4252.1, 16, 1], [5597.0, 17, 1], [2976.7, 18, 1], [605.0, 1, 2], [1947.7, 2, 2], [3219.3, 3, 2], [4217.6, 4, 2], 
[6917.6, 5, 2], [5644.3, 6, 2], [5303.2, 7, 2], [7005.9, 8, 2], 
[3274.3, 9, 2], [4200.6, 10, 2], [4231.6, 11, 2], [2571.4, 12, 2], [2985.5, 13, 2], [3464.5, 14, 2], [1949.5, 15, 2], [4579.3, 16, 2], [5967.8, 17, 2], [3328.5, 18, 2]]
```

Comment: I don't know if your code works o not, since I don't have a way to relate the BBU with RRH. For what I see you are only printing the distance and the RRH_id. I've tried to output it's BBU_id to which each RRH is connected but what I get does not match the correct output. How do can I print the BBU_id with is the value at distances[i][1]

Comment: Given that `distances` are calculated correctly you can verify the correctness by inspecting it in chuncks of `len(BBU)`(=18) and comparing with `connected_sites`.  I have  also added a bit more explanations.

Comment: Changing the the items to append to connected_sites (connected_sites.append(min_dist)), gives me the epected output structure and I can confirm that the output result is correct, since I have this code done in matlab. Thank you.